# python + Sqlite: How to save the changes into a new db file?

Tags: python, sqlite

After the changes were made to a db file, I want to save the data into a new db file.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Original.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
# make changes here.
conn.close() #Close without save

connA = sqlite3.connect('NewFile.db')
connA.commit() # Here is my problem. How to save the changed data into this new file?
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: My db file is huge. If I make a copy of it at the beginning, it takes to much time. I would rather let it run after I made the changes, to save the starting time.

Comment: Keep working with the same file, only make a simple file copy each time before a change, to a different name?

Comment: You've got to add code to create tables, add rows, etc. The two database files are completely disconnected and unrelated.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I thought about this method. But my db file is huge. If I make a copy of it at the beginning, it takes to much time. I would rather let it run after I made the changes, to save time.

Comment: @BryanOakley But all the changes are still in the original database. How to let the NewFile to read data from the old database file?

Answer (score 2):

Each databases have their own table, data, schema, etc. If you just commit those changes on a brand new file, errors will occur.

If you want to save the changed data into a new database, you can make a copy of current database file by using `shutil.copyfile` and then operate on the new database.